# How to create and delete the virtual directory and application from the IIS?

Tags: delphi, iis, iis-7.5

I am searching for the solution to create, edit and delete the `Virtual directory entry`  in **IIS**.

I am using following code: 
**Get the IIS Server root virtuakl directory**

```
function GetIISWebServer(WebServerIndex: integer = 1): Variant;
var
  BindContext: IBindCtx;
  Eaten: longint;
  Moniker: IMoniker;
  ServerRootDispatch: IDispatch;
  MonikerString: WideString;
const
  WebServiceMoniker = 'IIS://localhost/W3SVC';
begin
  MonikerString := WebServiceMoniker + '/' + IntToStr(WebServerIndex);
  OleCheck(CreateBindCtx(0, BindContext));
  OleCheck(MkParseDisplayName(BindContext, PWideChar(MonikerString), Eaten, Moniker));
  OleCheck(Moniker.BindToObject(BindContext, nil, IDispatch, ServerRootDispatch));

  if (ServerRootDispatch = nil) then
    raise Exception.Create('Unable to retrieve Server Root object using the Moniker "' + MonikerString + '"');

  Result := ServerRootDispatch;
end;

function GetIISWebServerRootVirtualDir(WebServerIndex: Integer = 1): Variant;
begin
  Result := GetIISWebServer(WebServerIndex).GetObject('IisWebVirtualDir', 'Root');
end;
```

**Check if Virtual Directory already exist**

```
function VirtualDirectoryExists(VirtualDirectoryName : String) : Boolean;
var
  BindContext: IBindCtx;
  Eaten: longint;
  Moniker: IMoniker;
  ObjectDispatch: IDispatch;
  VariantObject: Variant;
  WebVirtualDir: Variant;
begin
  OleCheck(CreateBindCtx(0, BindContext));
 try
  OleCheck(MkParseDisplayName(BindContext, 'IIS://localhost/W3SVC', Eaten, Moniker));
 except
  on E : Exception do
  begin
    ShowMessage(E.Message);
    Result := False;
    Exit;
  end;
 end;
  OleCheck(Moniker.BindToObject(BindContext, nil, IDispatch, ObjectDispatch));
  VariantObject := ObjectDispatch;
 try
  WebVirtualDir := VariantObject.GetObject('IisWebVirtualDir', '1/Root/' + VirtualDirectoryName);
  Result := True;
 except
   Result := False;
 end;
end;
```

**Remove the virtual directory**

```
function RemoveVirtualDirectory(VirtualDirectoryName, AppId : String; RemoveApp : Boolean) : Boolean;
var
  ServerRoot : Variant;
  Cat : ICOMAdminCatalog;
  Apps : ICatalogCollection;
  TmpComp : ICatalogObject;
  LTest: Variant;
  Idx : Integer;
  TmpStr: String;
 begin
  Result := True;
  // check if virtual derectory exist   
  if VirtualDirectoryExists(VirtualDirectoryName) then
  begin
    ServerRoot := GetIISWebServerRootVirtualDir;
   try
    ServerRoot.Delete('IisWebVirtualDir', VirtualDirectoryName);
   except
    Result := False;
   end;
   if RemoveApp then
   begin
     Cat := CoCOMAdminCatalog.Create;
     Apps := Cat.GetCollection('Applications') as ICatalogCollection;
     Apps.Populate;
     Idx := 0;
     TmpComp := GetCatalogObjectByName(Apps, AppId);
     if TmpComp <> nil then
     begin
       while Idx < Apps.Count do
       begin
         if Apps.Item[Idx] = TmpComp then
         begin
           TmpComp.Value['Deleteable'] := True;
           Apps.SaveChanges;
           Apps.Remove(Idx);
           Apps.SaveChanges;
         end
         else
           Inc(Idx);
       end;
     end;
   end;
  end;
end;
```

But the problem is when I am searching and deleting for the virtual directory it convert the web application icon to folder but does not delete it physically.

So because of that I am not able to recreate the same directory.
While creating the virtual directory I am getting error as `Can not create a file which is already present at the specified path`

Can anyone help me to find put the cause of the same .
and How I can delete and create a virtual directory using delphi.

I am using IIS 7.5 with windows 7 OS.

Any type of suggestion or help me be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.